# Remove dtype at the end of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm writing a method to create an array from data file. The method looks like:

```
import numpy
def readDataFile(fileName):
    try:
        with open(fileName, 'r') as inputs:
            data = None
            for line in inputs:
                line = line.strip()
                items = line.split('\t')
                if data == None:
                    data = numpy.array(items[0:len(items)]) 
                else:
                    data = numpy.vstack((data, items[0:len(items)]))
                return numpy.array(data)
    except IOError as ioerr:
        print 'IOError: ', ioerr
        return None
```

My data file contains lines of numbers, each of which is separated from each other by a tab, e.g:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

And I expect to receive an array as follows:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

However, the result contains `dtype` at the end of it:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]], dtype='|S9')
```

Because of it, I cannot perform some operations on the result, e.g. if I try to find the max value for each line using `result.max(0)`, I'll receive an error:

> TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type.

So, can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code and how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest fix is to use numpy's loadtxt:

```
data = numpy.loadtxt(fileName, dtype='float')
```

Just FYI, using `numpy.vstack` inside a loop is a bad idea. If you decide not to use `loadtxt`, you can replace your loop with the following to fix the dtype issue and eliminating the `numpy.vstack`.

```
data = [row.split('\t') for row in inputs]
data = np.array(data, dtype='float')
```

Update

Every time vstack is called it makes a new array, and copies the contents of the old arrays into the new one. This copy is roughly O(n) where n is the size of the array and if your loop runs n times the whole thing becomes O(n**2), in other words slow. If you know the final size of the array ahead of time, it's better to create the array outside the loop and fill the existing array. If you don't know the final size of the array, you can use a list inside the loop and call vstack at the end. For example:

```
import numpy as np
myArray = np.zeros((10,3))
for i in xrange(len(myArray)):
    myArray[i] = [i, i+1, i+2]

# or:
myArray = []
for i in xrange(10):
    myArray.append(np.array([i, i+1, i+2]))
myArray = np.vstack(myArray)
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works really well. But can you clarify why it is a bad idea to put numpy.vstack inside a loop? Cheers.

Answer (score 15):

Numpy array includes a method to do this job:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['A', 'B'])
a
# Returns: array(['A', 'B'],  dtype='|S1')

a.tolist()
# Returns ['A', 'B']
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html#numpy.ndarray.tolist

Comment: Then that list again need to be converted into array as this ... list = array_with_dtype.tolist() , 
arr = np.array(list)

Answer (score 11):

Here is how you change data types in numpy:

```
>>> x
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> x.astype('|S9')
array([['1', '2', '3'],
       ['4', '5', '6'],
       ['7', '8', '9']], 
      dtype='|S9')
>>> x.astype('Float64')
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
>>> x.astype('int')
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 4):

... Did you try turning them into numbers first?

```
items = [int(x) for x in line.split('\t')]
```