# Converting Comma delimted CSV to Tab delimted CSV in pandas

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I am using python I have a CSV file which had values separated by tab,
I applied a rule to each of its row and created a new csv file, the resulting dataframe is comma separated , I want this new csv to be tab separated as well. How can I do it ?
I understand using sep = '\t' can work but where do I apply it ?
I applied the following code but it didn't work either

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)
df_norm= df.apply(lambda x:np.where(x>0,x/x.max(),np.where(x<0,-x/x.min(),x)),axis=1)
df_norm.to_csv("file.csv", sep="\t")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: df_norm.to_csv("file.csv", sep="\t")

Comment: @TomMcLean Hello Thank you for the suggestion I had applied it as well, It didn't work, hence the doubt! attaching the results.

Comment: You should not post images of your code, you should always put it as text in a code block. Could you please run the line df_norm.head().to_clipboard() and copy the results into your question so that someone can fix your code?

Comment: if you saved with `\t` - `to_csv(..., sep="\t")` - then next you should read also with `\t` - `read_csv(..., sep="\t")` - but you read it with default separator comma - `read_csv(...)` - and this is your mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, the rule had changed the type to "object', because of which I was unable to perform any further operations. I followed [Remove dtype at the end of numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288757/remove-dtype-at-the-end-of-numpy-array/39170985), and converted my data frame to a list which solved the issue.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)
df_norm= df.apply(lambda x:np.where(x>0,x/x.max(),np.where(x<0,-x/x.min(),x)),axis=1)
df_norm=df_norm.tolist()
df_norm = np.squeeze(np.asarray(df_norm))
np.savetxt('result.csv', df_norm, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: you could put it as minimal working code. And you can mark it as accepted. And few minutes later you can upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried, this ?

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='\t')
```

Comment: i did but it didn't work I added the image of the result above

Comment: No, I meant loading the newly generated file.csv (your last image ) with sep = '\t'. Not telling about saving it, but reading it.

Comment: Oh i see! okayI tried that it also didn't work :/